# How to replace this kind of string using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I have a log file containing this kind of strings:

```
[1234(0) #1] 
[1234(1) #2] 
[1234(3) #0]
```

and so on... (notice a final whitespace in each string)

So, I need to replace those strings with nothing. I've tried to execute:

```
$ sed -i 's/\[1234\(\d\)\s#\d\]\s//g' log.txt
```

but it doesn't seem to work... Indeed if then I run:

```
$ grep '\[1234([0-9])\s#[0-9]\]\s' log.txt
```

I still receive those strings... What's wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to keep ? You say you want to remove something but not precisely what you want to keep. Is the logfile example complete ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the same string back except for the space -- and all the records are structured exactly the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You version of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) probably does not support `\s` and `\d`. Additionally, `(` and `)` do not need escaping by default. The following works for me

```
sed 's/\[1234([[:digit:]])[[:space:]]#[[:digit:]]\][[:space:]]//g' file
```

Comment: +1 nice answer. sed regular expressions manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

Comment: Thank you, that works! P.S.: you forgot `'` at the beginning of the regex. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you like using `\s` and `\d` you could use [ex](/questions/tagged/ex) instead of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), for in-place editing.
:

```
ex +'%s/\[1234(\d)\s#\d\]\s//g' +'wq' ./log.txt
```